# "hkcu\volatile environment" missing, hkcu\environment not read

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, login, environment-variables

This question is very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/414374/temp-environment-variable-occasionally-set-incorrectly). Suddenly, my `"HKCU\Volatile Environment"` keys disappeared, and my system no longer reads `HKCU\Environment` unless I reset it explicitly using `SETX` (which I think sends a [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011) to all active processes). I reset the volatile environment keys manually, but they are not being determined dynamically; they just stay at the values I set. If I do nothing some of the typical volatile environment keys are generated in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet` instead, but `HOMEPATH` & `HOMEDRIVE` are missing, and these process variables don't show up as system variables, although they show up in cmd.exe if you type `SET`. Explorer does seem slow to boot, but even if I run `msconfig` (haven't tried [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) yet) , and select diagnostic startup, I still get the same issue. Can somebody please help me? Using a startup batch file to trigger a read of the user variables is only a temporary fix. Thanks!

Comment: see my [workaround](http://superuser.com/a/507833/115481)